# file uploading in php

Tags: php, file-upload

Here my code

```
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["audio"]["name"] . "<br/>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["audio"]["type"] . "<br/>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["audio"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br/>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["audio"]["tmp_name"] . "<br/>";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["audio"]["tmp_name"],
    "/var/www/html/mnworld/upload/audiofile/" . $_FILES["audio"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "/var/www/html/mnworld/upload/audiofile/" . $_FILES["audio"]["name"];
```

I tried to upload file in this (/var/www/html/mnworld/upload/audiofile/) directory but its always empty its not showing any errors. I need to upload this directory

Comment: try using `var_dump($_FILES);` see what it contains, just to be sure did you put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form ? and also take note your first parameter in `move_uploaded_file()` should be a path and not the audio name

Comment: its comming like this array(1) { ["audio"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Koala.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpLsAnQ7" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(780831) } } @Drixson

Comment: check the write permission of the directory

Comment: @user2732605 use `chmod 777 /var/www/html/mnworld/upload/audiofile/`

Comment: is the `/var` inside root directory or in the current working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the permission of the folder where the files are to be stored is in  **777 mode** (both Read and write). If not, change the mode to `chmod 777`. And also make sure that the path to be stored should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the correct details. The problem is only the permission of the folder that unables you to move/copy the file.

Use this: `chmod 777 /var/www/html/mnworld/upload/audiofile/`